# How to draw marginal density function using R?

Tags: probability-distributions

suppose $f(x,y) = cxy^2$ is the joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$.
$0\le x\ ,\ y\le 2$.

> Q1: what value must $c$ have for this to be a pdf?
>
> Q2: what is the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$.
>
> Q3: draw a graph of each marginal density function using $R$.

Can anyone please help with the third question?
Also is the answer for Q1: $c= 3/16$?
Q2: $fx(x)=1/(2x)$  $fy(y)=3/(8y^2)$?

Many thanks